# C++ animated cursor

Tags: c++, animation, c++builder

I'm using this code to invoke animated cursor in C++ builder:

```
void __fastcall TcfListatArtikujtLst::FormActivate(TObject *Sender)
{
   ActiveControl = cxGrid1;
   Application->ProcessMessages();

   const int cnCursorID1 = 1;
   Screen->Cursors[cnCursorID1] = LoadCursorFromFile("cursors\\hourglas.ani");
   Cursor = cnCursorID1;

   try
   {
       dmDM1->prcArtikujt->Close();
       dmDM1->prcArtikujt->Parameters->Refresh();
       dmDM1->prcArtikujt->Prepared;

       dmDM1->CDSArtikujt->Data = dmDM1->DSPArtikujt->Data;
       dmDM1->CDSArtikujt->Open();
   }
   __finally
   {
       Screen->Cursor = crDefault;
   }
}
```

Problem is that animation takes effect atre try-finally block and doesn't retun do default cursor.

Cheers,
Nijazi Citaku

Comment: You have some formatting buttons above the editing text of the question. Don't be afraid to use them, to make your question and code easier to read :)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that the cursor is loaded but not changed until the Windows message loop continues.

Try a ProcessMessages AFTER the load cursor from file.

The cursor is not going away because you have not told the form to go back to a normal cursor.  You have told the Screen to go back to the normal cursor.

Try:

```
__finally
{
   Cursor = crDefault;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is ths solution :

```
void __fastcall TcfListatArtikujtLst::FormActivate(TObject *Sender) 
{ 
   ActiveControl = cxGrid1; 
   Application->ProcessMessages(); 

   const int cnCursorID1 = 1; 
   Screen->Cursors[cnCursorID1] = LoadCursorFromFile("cursors\\hourglas.ani"); 
   Application->ProcessMessages;
   Screen->Cursor = cnCursorID1; 

   try 
   { 
       dmDM1->prcArtikujt->Close(); 
       dmDM1->prcArtikujt->Parameters->Refresh(); 
       dmDM1->prcArtikujt->Prepared; 

       dmDM1->CDSArtikujt->Data = dmDM1->DSPArtikujt->Data; 
       dmDM1->CDSArtikujt->Open(); 
   } 
   __finally 
   { 
       Screen->Cursor = crDefault; 
   } 
}
```